# Minor mistake on resume and back ground check

Tags: software-industry

I just cleared a Software Developer interviews and they want to do a BGC on me. After reviewing my resume, I realize I made a minor mistake on my previous employment start date(June instead of July), and My job title was Programmer Analyst instead of Software Developer. I just wondering if that would affect my chance to get this job offer.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do nothing.

Many resumes are fine to have your start *year* as opposed to start *month*. Such a discrepancy is unlikely to come up in their search, especially since the months are so close the documentation may appear in either month and will seem legit.

As far as your title goes, this is another that is unlikely to have a problem during your background check. Both of those terms are essentially interchangeable (especially considering the kind of work being done in them.)

Contacting them to tell them about the problem can only do one thing: show them that you submitted an important document without doing the proper proofreading. Call me cynical, but this isn't the kind of message I'd like to send to someone considering me for a job.

You've already nailed the interview and they're willing to spend the money on a background check. That's a good sign. Don't blow it over details that, in the grand scheme of things, don't really matter.

Comment: Plus, if they reject you for making such minor mistakes, you probably don't want to work there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The folks doing these checks understand human error. Unless it looks like you were deliberately lying, it is unlikely to hurt you. However, best practice would probably be to call the company on Monday and tell them you just noticed these typos hadn't gotten corrected in the resume copy you gave them and would they like a corrected copy.

Answer (score 2):

I would let it slide. Seems like a minor mistake that will likely not get noticed. Not sure if it's worth the effort to set the record straight. More likely to confuse them and question your attention to detail. If they do find out and bring it up you would just say it was an honest mistake that you overlooked. Doubtful they hired you because you worked someplace one month longer or your title was different. As long as they are hiring you for something you can actually do I would just correct it on your resume for your next role. Good luck

Comment: Off by a month is no big deal - off by 6 months or a year is.  A generic job title that's less prestigious is no big deal - saying you had a senior role when you were a junior is.  As long as none of the mistakes would make you look *more* qualified, you're safe.